# Problema de redundância cíclica spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, referência-circular

Estou tentando injetar meu repository na minha classe consumer em uma aplicação spring boot simples que apenas salva uma mensagem do kafka em um banco db2.

Ao tentar subir ele pede que uma classe configuration seja criada usando bean para instanciar meu repository. Mesmo criando a classe de configuração ele retorna erro de dependência cíclica.

> Description:
>
> The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form
> a cycle:
>
> ┌──->──┐ |  getPortalOneRepository defined in class path resource
> [br/portalonestream/config/PortalOneConfig.class]
> └──<-──┘
>
> Action:
>
> Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are
> prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the
> dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible
> to break the cycle automatically by setting
> spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

Minha classe consumer:

```
/**
 * Recebe a mensagem do EventHub da Azure utilizando Kafka
 */
@Service
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaConsumer {

    private PortalOneRepository portalOneRepository;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topicout")
    public void consumeEventHubMessage(String consumerMessage) {
        log.info("Received message from kafka queue: {}", consumerMessage);

        //Convert string message to java object
        try {
            DocumentONE[] documentOne = objectMapper.readValue(consumerMessage, DocumentONE[].class);
            //Salvar cada mensagem no db2
            portalOneRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(documentOne));

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error receiving message: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Minha classe de configuração:

```
@Configuration
public class PortalOneConfig {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public PortalOneRepository getPortalOneRepository(){
        return context.getBean(PortalOneRepository.class);
        
    }


}
```

E esse e o repositório do db2:

```
@Repository
public interface PortalOneRepository extends JpaRepository<DocumentONE, Long> {
}
```

Qual seria a forma correta de injetar o repository na minha classe consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!
O problema era uma configuração no arquivo application.yml

> autoconfigure:
> exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

Após remover a aplicação voltou a subir normalmente!